# OpenOffice Automation Delphi how use a callfunction

Tags: delphi, automation, openoffice-calc

please help me with the following:
I want to determine the maximum value in an open office calc column using the OOoTools.pas
interface.
This as fas as I come:

```
Procedure FindMaximum(oMySheet : Variant);
Var
            oFuncService : Variant;
Begin
  oFuncService := CreateUnoService('com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess');
  ShowMessage(oFuncService.callFunction('MAX', VarArrayOf([10,20,50])));
End;
```

This works

Of course I want to fill in the values of a column like:

```
ShowMessage(oFuncService.callFunction('MAX', VarArrayOf([oMySheet.getCellRangeByName('K8:K10')])));
```

I get the message "com.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException:." why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am again.

Is it the `callFunction` method that gives this error or the `getCellRangeByName` method?

```
procedure FindMaximum(oMySheet : Variant);
var
  oFuncService : Variant;
  oCellRange: Variant;
  oResult: Variant;
begin
  oFuncService := CreateUnoService('com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess');

  //error here?
  oCellRange := oMySheet.getCellRangeByName('K8:K10');

  //or error here?
  oResult := oFuncService.callFunction('MAX', VarArrayOf([oCellRange]));

  ShowMessage(oResult);
end;
```

I have to say that I find the [documentation](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XFunctionAccess.html) a bit unclear.

When you have the error on the `callFunction` method in my above sample, try this:

```
//CellRange not wrapped in a VariantArray
oResult := oFuncService.callFunction('MAX', oCellRange);
```

Comment: The error occurs on     oResult := oFuncService.callFunction('MAX', VarArrayOf([oCellRange]));

Comment: @addelichtman: Is there maybe an invalid value in your K8:K10 range? Text instead of numeric value?

Comment: Absolutely shure the column only contains integers. Does the line oMySheet.getCellRangeByName('K8:K70'); return the contents of the column?

Comment: @addelichtman: Maybe it is a bug in the Automation bridge. When I do the same in Calc's macro editor it works. But when I try this in Delphi it just refuses to work. Even when I work with ValueObjects (Bridge_GetValueObject) to specify the exact types I get errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time I'll do the function by iterating through the cell values (will be much slower I expect) greetings Addelichtman